# Pandas when renaming a column, key error is encountered

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below code to rename a column

```
df.rename(columns = {'Long Name 1':'Court'}, inplace = True)
```

But encounter the below error

```
KeyError: "['Long Name 1'] not in index"
```

Not sure why there is an error. When I see the columns in the df, it exists

```
print(df.columns)
```

Result:

```
Index(['Activity', 'Date', 'Hirer Category', 'No of Slots', 'Slot Status', 'Start Time', 'Court', 'Long Name 1'], dtype='object')
```

Why am I not able to rename column 'Long Name 1'?

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem can't reproduce. I checked with dummy values but not found any error. You can see the screenshot and your code is working fine.
[Link to the Screenshot as I not have enough reputation to embed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANgbT.png)

Hope this helps. Thank you